# Is it possible to insert GameWidget(game: SpaceShooterGame()) in a column Widget. (Flutter Flame)

Tags: flutter, dart, flame

```
              Column(
                children: [
                  GameWidget(game: SpaceShooterGame()),
```

I got following message
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderConstrainedBox object was given an infinite size during layout.

How to do ?

I try   may widget around GameWidget  (row ,column  ..)
none is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Expanded` widget inside `Column`.

```
  Column(
        children: [
             Expanded(
               child: GameWidget(
                    game: SpaceShooterGame(),
                       ),
                     ),
                   ],
                 )
```

Comment: Merci. It is OK with your solution